# What is the ideal temperature and pressure to crack water?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, electrochemistry, water

Using sun mirrors and solar cells for electricity. What temperature, pressure and voltage ideal for cracking water.

[image]
<sub>Source: [NPR](https://www.npr.org/sections/alltechconsidered/2016/04/05/470810118/solar-and-wind-energy-may-be-nice-but-how-can-we-store-it)</sub>

[image]
<sub>[Source](https://thefraserdomain.typepad.com/energy/2006/03/huge_concentrat.html)</sub>

Would it take more or less electricity to crack water under pressure or in a liquid or vapor state?

Comment: Check this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_splitting#Solar-thermal, how will you pass electricity through water vapors?

Comment: @M.Farooq I want to say it could be done with laser filamentation.

Comment: @MaxW I don't think it so, water starts to spontaneously decay at $\approx 3000 ^\circ \rm C$. Plasma state starts to appear at $\approx 10000 ^\circ \rm C$. Mixed $\rm H$ and $\rm O$ plasma will be a neutral mix, there will be too hot for any chemical binding.

Comment: @MaxW Essentially, in a plasma state, all the elements are already long neutral chemically. Instead, new and interesting electromagnetic effects happen.

Comment: @M.Farooq It is a nice answer stub, in my opinion. I think it obviously closes out any gaseous phase. But it doesn't close out fluid water in elevated pressures. The question is, where is the efficiency optimum.

Comment: I think this question has potential, but you should organize your thoughts better so that the question is more clear.